# How to handle remaining funds after a crowdfund closes (from the tutorial)

Tags: solidity, dapps

The tutorial crowdfunding app has the following function:

```
/* checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign */
function checkGoalReached() afterDeadline {
    if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
        beneficiary.send(amountRaised);
        FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
    } else {
        for (uint i = 0; i < funders.length; ++i) {
          funders[i].addr.send(funders[i].amount);
          FundTransfer(funders[i].addr, funders[i].amount, false);
        }
    }

    beneficiary.send(this.balance); // send any remaining balance to beneficiary anyway
    crowdsaleClosed = true;
}
```

If in the 'else' statement all the funders get the amount they funded back, how there can be any left over balance to send to the beneficiary?

Comment: I suppose if the contract has a balance, i.e. someone had sent funds to the contract, then this would clear remaining funds from the contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial may be updated because there are 2 glaring improvements that should be made to that code snippet.

First, the return value of all `.send` should be checked and handled.

Second, state should generally be updated first, before sending funds.  So swap these lines:

```
beneficiary.send(this.balance); // send any remaining balance to beneficiary anyway
crowdsaleClosed = true;
```

---

To the question, generally contracts can receive funds by sending ETH to it directly, so there may be a code path where the balance can be higher than what funders have provided.